# Права на директорию внутри docker контейнера

Tags: docker

Есть приложение на Laravel, собираю docker образ php так:

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2

ADD . /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
&& chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
```

Корневая директория проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то, когда делаю `docker-compose build` появляется ошибка, что директория `storage` не существует

Comment: А почему вы решили что она должна существовать?

Comment: @andreymal, она есть в моем приложении. Добавил содержание `docker-compose` в описании вопроса

Comment: volumes подключаются ПОСЛЕ сборки образа, в момент запуска контейнера

Comment: @andreymal, пробовал так в Dockerfile `ADD . /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html`, но все равно ошибка

Comment: Во-первых, покажите докерфайл как конкретно это пробовали, во-вторых, покажите содержимое этого самого `.` и проверьте dockerignore

Comment: @andreymal, добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: Если докерфайл лежит не в корневой директории, то у меня есть сомнения что ADD/COPY будут копировать то что вы ожидаете (но точное поведение докера в этом случае я к сожалению подзабыл)

Comment: @andreymal, да, dockerfile находится в `/docker/php/`. Мне вместо `.` нужно указать что то другое?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем использовать COPY и volume в одно и то же место -- /var/www/html;
видимо, они сконфликтовали;

может сделать volume подальше, в /app_storage каком-нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Если Docker пишет, что директории не существует, то скорее всего это так и есть.

- проверьте создана ли вообще `storage`
- проверьте путь к ней
- после проверки проверьте правильность пути при выполнении `chmod`

Comment: После запуска контейнера, по этому пути есть такая директория